# Retrieve Selected Item from Dropdownlist In MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list in the controller and my code looks like this.

```
ViewBag.Organizations = _frontendUserService.GetOrganizationByClientId(Constants.ClientId);
```

And I'm setting this list in my View Page with a Dropdownlist.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Organization.OrganizationId, 
    new SelectList(
        ViewBag.Organizations as System.Collections.IEnumerable, 
        "OrganizationId", 
        "OrganizationName"),
    "-- Select Organization --")
```

Here I get the OrganizationId as the selected item. Instead I want to retrieve the selected item as an "Organization" object in the POST request to my action method.

Actually why I wanted to get the entire object here is, because when I'm querying the database by OrganizationId I'm getting following error.

```
Error: sequence contains more than one matching element
```

In my application I'm using repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done, but I don't see the point in it. It's most likely a lot more efficient to fetch it from the database again instead of trying to do what you are asking.

Comment: Currently what I'm trying to do is fetching from the database. But I'm getting following error when querying by OrganizationId.

Error: sequence contains more than one matching element

Comment: That's another question. right? In this question you are asking how you can get the entire object in the POST by using a select list. Either edit the question and add relevant information or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar, but struggled - ended up using some of the code of this site and the generator tool, works quite well: http://www.mvc3razor.com/sample-code/